# How can linear response give DC conductivity when the formalism doesn't have dissipation at all?

Tags: conductors, electronic-band-theory, bloch-oscillation

A lot of textbook or lecture note that teach linear response theory would calculate AC conductivity first and then say that the DC conductivity can be obtained from taking the limit of frequency to zero. I don't understand how this can be possibly true.

The AC connectivity might be calculatable from linear response with the assumption that the frequency is high enough that the oscillation happens on a time scale much faster than dissipative collision with phonon or impurity (and that first order time dependent approximation is valid throughout). However, in the limit of frequency to zero, the assumption will no long be true.

Furthermore, since the formalism doesn't involve dissipation, electron that moves down a potential slope, will indefinitely accumulate higher and higher kinetic energy (the electron will go up in bands indefinitely... or the electron would do bloch oscillations without consistently going down the potential slope). I think this means only formalism that explicitly consider dissipation can possibly give DC conductivity.

Why do textbooks claim taking frequency to zero can give DC conductivity? Are they simply just wrong?

Comment: The semi-classical collision frequency of electrons with impurities and phonons is not the AC frequency of the macroscopic system. Linear systems theory doesn't have anything to do with physics, to begin with. There are plenty of linear systems that can not be implemented with physical means or that can not be implemented in a cost efficient manner. That's why we prefer digital signal processing these days.

Comment: The electron collision frequency is really really fast, so if your frequency of interest is low enough MHz and below easily), then you can ignore specifics of the electron collisions. The electrons really don’t think 50/60 Hz is any different than dc.